# Email flagged as spam or rejected by recipient mail server

Tags: windows-server-2008, email, smtp, spf, dkim

I have configured SMTP service on a windows 2008 server. All the emails sent by the SMTP service are flagged as spam or they are rejected by the recipient of the email.

In the header of the email I noticed

```
X-AUTH-Result: FAIL
X-SID-Result: FAIL
```

and

```
spf=fail .... x-hmca=fail**
```

I hope someone could explain why the verification of email is failing.

The full email header:

```
x-store-info:sbevkl2QZR7OXo7WID5ZcdV2tiiWGqTnu/L+UA0lIUkdujfCEDe9TejEOcHgYvKQaXRRlSrWyA9F82Xi5yFzUoAr8R2ZN2NgyjgYojpTVH5cVYPT0s7sOARewS8iL50FwtnQ3lCq1F0=
Authentication-Results: hotmail.com; spf=fail (sender IP is 19x.18x.12x.16x) smtp.mailfrom=test@example.com; dkim=none header.d=example.com; x-hmca=fail header.id=test@example.com
X-SID-PRA: test@example.com
X-AUTH-Result: FAIL
X-SID-Result: FAIL
X-Message-Status: n:n
X-Message-Delivery: Vj0xLjE7dXM9MDtsPTA7YT0xO0Q9MTtHRD0xO1NDTD0z
X-Message-Info: NhFq/7gR1vQhAh5Uns46VTwR4xRSvuAW0HDEmwtlGrJLRuPzYbcrweQc9/vi5y7tv/wPRYnDZxALMzu9XvL/UwdbytE0Lv6jUK7MkoBTn/O4Oia7TV+9F0vdvB/+1N9IKagPiODLVNjh/MYiPUW3i/ADUKyMTaK95RazlUvygznVkxGQaoJMveekXLnmzoSYKHHVVeQpF/Tka0PsrTomstRGz57bj50Y
Received: from VPSxxx ([19x.18x.12x.16x]) by SNT0-MC2-F42.Snt0.hotmail.com with Microsoft SMTPSVC(6.0.3790.4900);
     Mon, 24 Feb 2014 03:06:51 -0800
Received: from VPSxxx ([127.0.0.1]) by VPSxxx with Microsoft SMTPSVC(6.0.3790.4675);
     Mon, 24 Feb 2014 12:06:51 +0100
thread-index: Ac8xUIUYu8qH5earTVaHpdUmHexXQA==
Thread-Topic: test
From: "test" <test@example.com>
To: <xxxxx@hotmail.com>
Subject: test
Date: Mon, 24 Feb 2014 12:06:51 +0100
Message-ID: <422D954CFCD743E9B5DD2BAB5713896E@VPSxxx>
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain;
    charset="iso-8859-1"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
X-Mailer: Microsoft CDO for Windows 2000
Content-Class: urn:content-classes:message
Importance: normal
Priority: normal
X-MimeOLE: Produced By Microsoft MimeOLE V6.00.3790.4913
Return-Path: test@example.com
X-OriginalArrivalTime: 24 Feb 2014 11:06:51.0731 (UTC) FILETIME=[851AE230:01CF3150]

test
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of SPF which is a DNS setting.

Basically you are putting up a server to send emails, but the server is not in the list of servers that can send emails for that domain.

SPF - a record in the DNS system - tells for the domain which servers are alowed to send emails.

Simple like that.

I suggest - routing your emails through an authorized server.

That is for fxxx.com in your example.

http://www.kitterman.com/spf/validate.html

can be used to get the SPF record.

SPF was created to fight people just using other peoples domains as sender ;) Spam basically. You make sure your server looks like a spam sernder.

Comment: The fxxx.com hostes a my pop3 email server and 19x.18x.12x.16x is used for hosting the smtp. How should the SPF txt look like? is this correct v=spf1 include:mail.fxxx.com ip4:19x.18x.12x.16x ~all ?

Answer (score 0):

The sender domain's SPF record doesn't include the IP address or domain name of your server.

You should update your SPF record in DNS so that your server is included there.

Comment: I updated it to ´v=spf1 include:mail.fxxx.com ip4:19x.18x.12x.16x ~all´ but im not sure if this is correct